# Second optional capturing group depending on optional delimiter in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm sorry for asking this maybe duplicate question. I checked the existing questions and answers about *optional capturing groups*. I tried some things but I'm not able to translate the answer to my own example.

This are two imput lines

```
id:target][label
id:target
```

I would like to capture `id:` (group 1), `target` (group 2) and if `][` is present `label` (group 3).

The used regex (Python regex) only works on the first line ([live example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JPPV0W/1)).

```
^(.+:)(.*)\]\[(.*)
```

[image]

In the other examples I don't get what the regex makes a capturing group optional. And maybe the delimiter `][` used by me also mix up with my understanding problem.

One thing I tried was this

```
^(.+:)(.*)(\]\[(.*))?
```

This doesn't work as expected
[image]

Comment: Does this what solves your problem: ```(.+:)([^\]]*)(?:(?:\]\[)(.*))?``` https://regex101.com/r/1rBTu4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern using an anchor at the end, a negated character class for group 1, a non greedy quantifier for group 2 and then optionally match a 3rd part:

```
^([^:]+:)(.*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^:]+:)` Group 1, match 1+ chars other than `:` and then match `:` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(.*?)` Group 2, match any char, as few as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `]\[` Match `][`
  - `(.*)` Group 3, match any character
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouSIWt/1)

If you are only matching for example word characters, this you might consider:

```
^([^:]+:)(\w+)(?:]\[(\w+))?
```

See a another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rd46x5/1)

Comment: Thanks for reply. It seems to me that you optimized my regex exceptional from my question. e.g. `[^:]` It would be great if you could add some more explanations about that. Why is `([^:]+:)` better than `^(.+:)` for example?

Comment: @buhtz I have added an explanation. The part `^(.+:)` first matches until the end of the string as the `.` can match any character including the `:`, and will then backtrack to the last occurrence of `:` If you use a negated character class `[^:]+:` you can not cross matching a `:` and will then stop at the first occurrence.